# ¿a que tipo de estrucura de dato son las tablas de las bases de datos relacionales?, ¿podrian considerarse tablas hash?

Tags: algoritmos

me surgió la duda porque estoy tomando un curso de estructura de datos. en este estoy aprendiendo a codificar de manera más eficiente según el problema que deseo resolver, para ello me enseñan algunas estructuras de datos, tablas hash. arreglos, objetos, entre otros. En el fondo, mejores prácticas de codificación. Mi pregunta apunta a cómo almacenan la información las bases de datos, se almacenan de forma más parecida a varias tablas hash unidas por índices? o cómo?

Comment: depende como quiera la base de datos. en general son tablas planas... y las estructuras se usan enlos indices

Comment: podrian comportarse como arreglos o algun tipo de estructura que se conozca? o tal vez estoy mezclando conceptos?

Comment: No hay estructura... hay datos y punteros a los mismos. Podria decirse que es un arreglo... pero tambien depende de la base de datos... no hay una estructura basica.

Comment: Puedes verlas como un arreglo de estructuras. La estructura sería los campos de cada fila de la tabla. El arreglo sería la secuencia de filas. Para mejorar la eficiencia de las búsquedas se construyen indices, que serían tablas hash siendo la clave (hash) los valores de la columna índice, y los valores los índices de las filas en cuestión. Así, para buscar un elemento por el valor de uno de los campos se hace el hash del valor, se busca en la tabla hash y se obtiene el índice del arreglo que contiene ese elemento.

Comment: Toma en cuenta que no es lo mismo almacenar en memoria que en disco. Es mas fácil implementar estructuras de datos sólo en memoria, en cambio, las bases de datos dependen de estructuras de organización más complejas y estrechamente relacionadas con el sistema de archivos; por lo que suelen tener varios mecanismos y una sola operación puede usar varios de ellos. ¿Cómo implementarías una pila -ó x estructura de datos- en en archivo? Entre los ceros-unos y un conjunto de registros existen varios niveles de abstracción.

Answer (score 1):

Depende de la base de datos.

Usualmente la implementación se hace con un [Arbol-B](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rbol-B). Es una estructura de datos que generaliza el concepto de un árbol binario al permitir que los nodos contengan más de dos hijos. La estructura permite búsquedas, inserciones y eliminaciones en tiempo logarítmico. Además, su estructura es óptima para su funcionamiento en otros tipos de memoria como discos.